# Windows Batch: If condition is not validated

Tags: batch-file, command-line

Here is my code

```
ECHO off
CLS
ECHO List of VMs:
ECHO .............
cd /D "F:\VMs"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /s/b *.vmx') do set /a num+=1&set VM[!num!]=%%i 
set numberOfVMs=0
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set VM[') do (
    set /a numberOfVMs+=1
    echo !numberOfVMs! -^> %%s
)
ECHO.
ECHO List of Running VMs:
ECHO .....................
set num=-1
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('vmrun -T ws list') do (
    set /a num+=1
    if !num! NEQ 0 set RUNNINGVM[!num!]=%%i
)
set numberOfRunningVMs=0
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set RUNNINGVM[') do (
    set /a numberOfRunningVMs+=1
    echo !numberOfRunningVMs! -^> %%s
)
ECHO.
ECHO List of Available VMs:
ECHO .......................
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %numberOfVMs%) do ( 
    ::echo !VM[%%x]!
    for /l %%y in (1, 1, %numberOfRunningVMs%) do (
            echo !VM[%%x]!
            echo !RUNNINGVM[%%y]!
        if "!VM[%%x]!"=="!RUNNINGVM[%%y]!" (
            echo "success"
        )
    )
)
```

**Array varibale 'VM' has below values:**

F:\VMs\PD-UI-Tests-Win10-x64-Office2016-32bit.vmwarevm\Windows-10-x64.vmx

F:\VMs\PD-UI-Tests-Win10-x64-Office2016-64bit.vmwarevm\Windows-10-x64.vmx

F:\VMs\PD-UI-Tests-Win7-x64-Office2013-32bit.vmwarevm\Windows7-x64-RTM.vmx

**Array varibale 'RUNNINGVM' has below values:**

F:\VMs\PD-UI-Tests-Win7-x64-Office2013-32bit.vmwarevm\Windows7-x64-RTM.vmx

But, the final if condition never becomes 'true' although the VM[3] is equal to RUNNINGVM[1]. What am i missing? Please help

Comment: what's the output?  if you turn echo on right after "List of Available VMs:", does that show anything interesting?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `::`-style comments within a code-block as it is actually a broken label, and labels break code-blocks. Use `rem` instead.